# Open native maps in Windows phone 8 application on button click

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

Is there a way to open Bing maps that are inbuilt to Windows phone on click of a button. If you have used the Foresquare app, it loads bing maps and show the destination latitude and longitude when you click the directions button. I want to do the exact same thing. Please help me with any resource you have.
Until now I tried the code in this link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj710324%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Problem is when I click the button it says do you want to search an app in the appstore. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use BingMapsDirectionsTask like this (just replace latitude and longitude with yours):

```
BingMapsDirectionsTask bingMapsDirectionsTask = new BingMapsDirectionsTask();
GeoCoordinate spaceNeedleLocation = new GeoCoordinate(47.6204,-122.3493);
LabeledMapLocation spaceNeedleLML = new LabeledMapLocation("Space Needle", spaceNeedleLocation);
bingMapsDirectionsTask.End = spaceNeedleLML;
bingMapsDirectionsTask.Show();
```

You can reed more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394024(v=vs.105).aspx) about Bind Maps directions task.

Comment: I edited my answer because I think you actually need BingMapsDirectionsTask not BingMapsTask.

Comment: DOUBLE THANKS. Yes BingMapsDirectionsTask is exactly what I needed. :) Thanks again.